# Upgraded to EF6 blew up Universal provider session state for Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that using the Universal providers for session state:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" sqlConnectionString="DefaultConnection" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

When I upgraded to entity framework 6 I now get this error: `Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.`

I tried adding the reference to System.Data.Entity.dll back in but that didn't work and I know that your not suppose to add that with the new entity framework..

Comment: Microsoft knows Universal Provider doesn't works with EF6 and hasn't fixed it yet: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801350/microsoft-aspnet-providers-core-incompatible-with-ef6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I removed the 1.2 version of ASP.NET Universal Providers and installed Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers for LocalDB v1.1 from NuGet and it works fine. I use a standard SQL Server 2008R2 installation but this provider works fine.

Comment: I'll have to try this out

Comment: I ended up reverting back to EF 5.. Sorry I'll have to wait until I try to upgrade again but that won't be happening for a while

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to solve, so had I rollback to a previous version.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0-rc1 -Pre
```